# Use a Socks5 Proxy in Flash Player

Tags: flash, ssh-tunnel, socks5

**Hello,**

I'm using PuTTY to create a Socks5 Proxy via SSH. It works great in firefox.

But Adobe Flash Player does not seem to use it at all, how can I route my traffic to my server in Flash?

I am using windows vista.

The server is running Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Flash is notorious for ignoring browser proxy settings. While this is a huge security risk, it's also a problem in your scenario.

Comment: Yep, but when you need it - it's a pain, I mostly run my browsers with flash off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with proxying is that every application you use has to specifically support proxy. Flash player, for example, doesn't seem to have SOCKS support.

I've developed software (tun2socks) that allows you to forward **all** TCP and optionally UDP through a SOCKS5 proxy, system-wide, without requiring any application support (which Flash is missing). To put it very simply, my software simulates a network interface and a virtual router behind that interface which forwards all connections through a SOCKS proxy, and by using it as the default gateway you get proxying for everything. The following guide explains using tun2socks with SSH forwarding (exactly what you want).

http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks

It it a little clumsy to set up however. If you want to automate it, you're on your own.
If you follow the guide successfully, all your programs will go through the proxy automatically, and you should disable proxy in the browser itself.

Comment: Thanks! I later find an alternative: proxifier it has a portable version so I might just buy that!

Comment: I wonder if I do this in a docker container without changing host operating system networking.